# Regex Patternst Match Wrong Strings

Tags: regex

There is my regex

```
\[a:section(.*)\](.*)\[\/a:section\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/wtN6Rk/1

I wanna detect like this

```
Group1 : asasasas   
Group2 : [a:widget type=blog][a:widget type=blog][a:widget type=blog]
```

But my regex code match wrong, How can I fix it?

Edit : If I don't use "[" string in group2, It works what I want.

Comment: The problem comes from the first `.*`. Two solutions: 1) use a non-greedy quantifier, 2) replace the dot with a character class that excludes the closing square bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy. It will matches any character, as many as possible.

Instead, you should better use `.*?`, which is the lazy alternative (matches any character as few as possible).

You can test the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/34rRE5/1).

---

Another option indicated by @Casimir et Hippolyte may be to replace the dot with a character class that excludes the closing square bracket, like that `[^]]`. It's also faster (54 steps instead of 74).

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fxN7m5/1).